# MongoDB multiply values inside two arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need help with multiplying values in an array of objects to get an output.

Here is my JSON

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b919a785cb288f7d5311846"),
    "nome" : "Antonio",
    "cod_produtor" : "PR001",
    "morada" : {
        "rua" : "Rua dos Carvalhos",
        "n_porta" : 12.0,
        "cod_postal" : "4567-123"
    },
    "data-registo" : ISODate("2017-07-22T03:41:20.201+0000"),
    "colheita" : {
        "cod_colheita" : "COL001",
        "ano" : 2018.0,
        "tipo_maça" : "Ambrosia",
        "precario" : [ 
            {
                "valor" : "0-60",
                "preço" : 0.1
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "60-65",
                "preço" : 0.12
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "65-70",
                "preço" : 0.15
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "70-75",
                "preço" : 0.17
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "75-80",
                "preço" : 0.2
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "80+",
                "preço" : 0.23
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "85-90",
                "preço" : 0.25
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "90+",
                "preço" : 0.3
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "DEFEITO",
                "preço" : 0.05
            }
        ],
        "Lote" : {
            "Número Lote" : "FE9450H",
            "Peso" : 4495.0,
            "calibragem" : [ 
                {
                    "valor" : "0-60",
                    "quantidade" : 22.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "60-65",
                    "quantidade" : 224.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "65-70",
                    "quantidade" : 624.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "70-75",
                    "quantidade" : 1183.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "75-80",
                    "quantidade" : 1424.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "80+",
                    "quantidade" : 911.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "85-90",
                    "quantidade" : 45.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "90+",
                    "quantidade" : 6.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "DEFEITO",
                    "quantidade" : 54.0
                }
            ],
            "TOTAL" : 4493.0,
            "DIFERENÇA" : -2.0
        }
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b91a8f65cb288f7d5311b50"),
    "nome" : "João",
    "cod_produtor" : "PR002",
    "morada" : {
        "rua" : "Rua dos Travessas",
        "n_porta" : 169.0,
        "cod_postal" : "9871-456"
    },
    "data-registo" : ISODate("2016-12-24T08:43:20.201+0000"),
    "colheita" : {
        "cod_colheita" : "COL005",
        "ano" : 2018.0,
        "tipo_maça" : "Golden",
        "precario" : [ 
            {
                "valor" : "0-60",
                "preço" : 0.1
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "60-65",
                "preço" : 0.12
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "65-70",
                "preço" : 0.15
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "70-75",
                "preço" : 0.17
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "75-80",
                "preço" : 0.2
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "80+",
                "preço" : 0.23
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "85-90",
                "preço" : 0.25
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "90+",
                "preço" : 0.3
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "DEFEITO",
                "preço" : 0.05
            }
        ],
        "Lote" : {
            "Número Lote" : "FE1283961",
            "Peso" : 1234.0,
            "calibragem" : [ 
                {
                    "valor" : "0-60",
                    "quantidade" : 22.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "60-65",
                    "quantidade" : 101.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "65-70",
                    "quantidade" : 223.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "70-75",
                    "quantidade" : 183.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "75-80",
                    "quantidade" : 424.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "80+",
                    "quantidade" : 11.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "85-90",
                    "quantidade" : 5.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "90+",
                    "quantidade" : 6.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "DEFEITO",
                    "quantidade" : 54.0
                }
            ],
            "TOTAL" : 1029.0,
            "DIFERENÇA" : 205.0
        }
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b91a9855cb288f7d5311b72"),
    "nome" : "Antonio",
    "cod_produtor" : "PR001",
    "morada" : {
        "rua" : "Rua dos Carvalhos",
        "n_porta" : 12.0,
        "cod_postal" : "4567-123"
    },
    "data-registo" : ISODate("2017-07-22T03:41:20.201+0000"),
    "colheita" : {
        "cod_colheita" : "COL001",
        "ano" : 2017.0,
        "tipo_maça" : "Ambrosia",
        "precario" : [ 
            {
                "valor" : "0-60",
                "preço" : 0.1
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "60-65",
                "preço" : 0.12
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "65-70",
                "preço" : 0.15
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "70-75",
                "preço" : 0.17
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "75-80",
                "preço" : 0.2
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "80+",
                "preço" : 0.23
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "85-90",
                "preço" : 0.25
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "90+",
                "preço" : 0.3
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "DEFEITO",
                "preço" : 0.05
            }
        ],
        "Lote" : {
            "Número Lote" : "FE9450H",
            "Peso" : 1000.0,
            "calibragem" : [ 
                {
                    "valor" : "0-60",
                    "quantidade" : 50.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "60-65",
                    "quantidade" : 150.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "65-70",
                    "quantidade" : 200.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "70-75",
                    "quantidade" : 250.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "75-80",
                    "quantidade" : 150.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "80+",
                    "quantidade" : 100.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "85-90",
                    "quantidade" : 45.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "90+",
                    "quantidade" : 15.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "DEFEITO",
                    "quantidade" : 40.0
                }
            ],
            "TOTAL" : 1000.0,
            "DIFERENÇA" : 0.0
        }
    }
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b91ab8c5cb288f7d5311bed"),
    "nome" : "Antonio",
    "cod_produtor" : "PR001",
    "morada" : {
        "rua" : "Rua dos Carvalhos",
        "n_porta" : 12.0,
        "cod_postal" : "4567-123"
    },
    "data-registo" : ISODate("2017-07-22T03:41:20.201+0000"),
    "colheita" : {
        "cod_colheita" : "COL001",
        "ano" : 2017.0,
        "tipo_maça" : "Ambrosia",
        "precario" : [ 
            {
                "valor" : "0-60",
                "preço" : 0.1
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "60-65",
                "preço" : 0.12
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "65-70",
                "preço" : 0.15
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "70-75",
                "preço" : 0.17
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "75-80",
                "preço" : 0.2
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "80+",
                "preço" : 0.23
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "85-90",
                "preço" : 0.25
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "90+",
                "preço" : 0.3
            }, 
            {
                "valor" : "DEFEITO",
                "preço" : 0.05
            }
        ],
        "Lote" : {
            "Número Lote" : "FE9450H",
            "calibragem" : [ 
                {
                    "valor" : "0-60",
                    "quantidade" : 50.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "60-65",
                    "quantidade" : 150.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "65-70",
                    "quantidade" : 200.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "70-75",
                    "quantidade" : 250.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "75-80",
                    "quantidade" : 150.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "80+",
                    "quantidade" : 100.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "85-90",
                    "quantidade" : 45.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "90+",
                    "quantidade" : 15.0
                }, 
                {
                    "valor" : "DEFEITO",
                    "quantidade" : 40.0
                }
            ],
            "TOTAL" : 1000.0,
            "DIFERENÇA" : 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

and what i need to do is multiply the values `colheita.precario` with `colheita.Lote.calibragem` to get a sum of them. inside `colheita.precario` you have the `valor` and `preço` and inside `colheita.Lote.calibragem` you have `valor` and `quantidade`. The field `valor` must match and then multiply `preço` * `quantidade`

Actually i have two different approaches. But none of them is working.
I was thinking in something like this:

*USING STUDIO 3T*

**Stage 1 - match**

Here i need to match to different things

```
{
    "cod_produtor" : "PR001", 
    "colheita.ano" : 2017
}
```

**Stage 2 - project**

```
{
    // specifications
    _id : "$colheita.Lote.Número Lote",
    total: {
        $sum:[
            { 
                "$multiply": [
                    "$colheita.precario.0.preço", 
                    "$colheita.Lote.0.quantidade"
                ] 
            },
            { 
                "$multiply" : [
                    "$colheita.precario.1.preço", 
                    "$colheita.Lote.1.quantidade"
                ] 
            }
        ]
   }
}
```

But this is not working because it gives an error:

> "The `$sum` accumulator is a unary operator"

Really thankfull for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below project in 3.4 aggregation.

[`$range`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) to iterate over `colheita.precario` inside[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and output value containing array fields with multiplication of preco and quantidade.

[`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) expression with index ( from `$range` (ix) ) to output the colheita.precario and Lote.calibragem element.

[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) with [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to output the sum of array values.

```
{
  "$project":{"total":{
    "$sum":{
      "$map":{
        "input":{"$range":[0,{"$size":"$colheita.precario"}]},
        "as":"ix",
        "in":{
          "$let":{
            "vars":{
              "pre":{"$arrayElemAt":["$colheita.precario","$$ix"]},
              "cal":{"$arrayElemAt":["$colheita.Lote.calibragem","$$ix"]}
            },
            "in":{"$multiply":["$$pre.preço","$$cal.quantidade"]}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can use below aggregation

```
db.state.aggregate(

// Pipeline
[
    // Stage 1
    {
        $unwind: {
            path : "$colheita.precario",
            includeArrayIndex : "arrayIndex", // optional
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : false // optional
        }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
        $unwind: {
            path : "$colheita.Lote.calibragem",
            includeArrayIndex : "arrayIndex", // optional
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : false // optional
        }
    },

    // Stage 3
    {
        $project: {
             "total": {
                    "$cond": { 
                        "if": { "$eq": [ "$colheita.precario.valor", "$colheita.Lote.calibragem.valor" ] }, 
                        "then": { $multiply: [ "$colheita.precario.preço", "$colheita.Lote.calibragem.quantidade" ] },
                        "else": 0
                    }
             }
        }
    },

    // Stage 4
    {
        $group: {
            "_id":"$_id",
            totalAmount: { $sum: "$total" }
        }
    },
]);
```